# Show carousel only if there are images. (Bootstrap carousel in Wordpress site with images added using Advanced Custom Fields)

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, advanced-custom-fields

I have a custom post type that may or may not include images to display in a carousel/slideshow. How can I have the carousel display ONLY if there have been images added to the post via Advanced Custom Fields? Below is the code I have so far. It works other than if there aren't images associated with the post, the frontend still shows the carousel controls and whatnot.

To further this, it'd be great to know how to have the indicators auto populate with the number of images added. As of now I have the indicators commented out.

```
<!-- slideshow -->
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <!-- <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    </ol> -->

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <?php if( have_rows('timeline_images') ): ?>
            <?php while( have_rows('timeline_images') ): the_row(); 
                // vars
                $image = get_sub_field('timeline_image');
                ?>

                <div class="item">
                    <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt'] ?>" title="<?php echo $image['title'] ?>" />
                </div>

            <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
<!-- /slideshow -->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do the same with your indicators as you do with your images (not tested):

```
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">      
       <?php if( have_rows('timeline_images') ): ?>
          <?php 
             $carrousselCount = 0;
             while( have_rows('timeline_images') ): the_row();
             $carrousselCount++;
          ?> 
            // indicators
            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="<?php echo $carrousselCount ?>" class="<?php echo $carrousselCount === 0 ? 'active' : '' ?>"></li>
          <?php endwhile; ?>
       <?php endif; ?>
      <!-- end ol -->
    </ol>
   </div>
```

Comment: This seems to work except that `data-slide-to=` is equal to 0 on every line item.

Comment: Yes I forgot $carrousselCount++ in the while loop (updated now)

Comment: That did the trick. I changed `$carrousselCount = 0;` to `$carrousselCount = -1;` because the first number needs to be 0.